# Pandas Dataframe date reformat

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (image supplied) where there is inconsistent dates, I need to add 20 after the second bracket, is there a formula I can apply to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and `dayfirst=True` in order to remove any ambiguity: "13/08/16" can be interpreted both like "2016-08-13" or like "2013-08-16"

```
# df is eplData
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(df)

# Output
         date       date2
0  13/05/2018  13/05/2018
1    13/08/16  13/08/2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert that column into a datetime column like this:

```
eplData['column_name'] = pd.to_datetime(eplData['column_name'])
```

There are also specific ways you can format the datetime column. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)